# prove the set is bounded above - solution check (with progress and solution

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $a\in \Bbb R, a>0$ and $p\in$ $\Bbb N\backslash\{0\}$ and $B:=\{x\in \Bbb R: 0 \le x, x^p\le a\}$

1. prove that B is bounded above
2. For $ c:= \sup B$; $c^p=a$
3. The equation $y^p=a$ in $(0, \infty)$ has the unique solution of c.

So my attempt:

Since $a> 0 $ and $p\ge1$ and $\forall x \in B,x\ge 0$, $x^p\ge0$, $(x+1)^p>x^p$. And since $x\in\Bbb B$ is a real number, $(x+1)$ must also be a real number. Hence the set B is bounded above. (However, I do believe that I should mention something about square root for real numbers, that's the title of the question) no sure thou.

For b) Since we proved the set is bounded above, there must exist a supremum. A supremum is an upper bound itself. Since $x^p\le a,x\le\sqrt[p]{a}$. And also since $(x+\ell)^p>x^p \forall\ell>0$, we can conclude the supremum of b is $x^p=a=c$

How does this look to you? I won't show my c since I think a and b are not very correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more or less correct, although you have some unnescessary and some missing arguments. If I’m correct this is part of the proof to the existence of the $p$-th root, thus you should not use roots here.

For 1: Rather than $(x+1)^p$ consider $(x+t)$ for any $t>0$. The binomial formula gives you $x^p+R$ with $R>0$. Thus the function is strictly monotonous. What you are now missing is a good argument for why this means that there exists such a bound. For example you can argue that $x^p\xrightarrow{x\to\infty} \infty$. Thus there exists some $x_0$ so that $x_0^p > a$. Due to monotony the set is thus bounded by $x_0$.

For 2: You do not need the roots. If $c$ is the sup then there exists a sequence $x_n$ in $B$ that converges to $c$. But as $x_n^p\leq a$ we also have for the limit $c^p\leq a$. But if $c^p< a$ then you need to argue that there is some $y>c$ with $y^p\leq a$. In that case: It is easy to see that $c\neq 0$, as there exists an $n\in\mathbb N$ so that $1/n < \min(a,1)$. Then $(1/n)^p\leq 1/n) < a$. But if $c\neq 0$ then we can take $1\leq a/c^p$. Now if this was $<$ then take $0<a/c^p-1$.

From the binomial formula we get that $(1+x)^p = \sum_{i=0}^p {p\choose i} x^i < 1+C_px$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$ for some constant $C_p\in\mathbb N$. (Since all $x^i \leq x^1$ for $i\geq 1$, then $C_p = \sum_{i=1}^p {p\choose i} = 2^p - 1$).

Thus we find an $n$ so that $1/n < a/(c^pC_p)$ and thus $(1+1/n)^p < 1+C_p/n < a/c^p$. Then $c(1+1/n)>c$ but $(c(1+1/n))^p < c^p a/c^p = a$.

For 3 you’ll need to show that this solution $c$ is unique, so if $y_1^p=y_2^p = a$, then $y_1=y_2$. For this you can use the strict monotonity.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer...Sorry i didnt get the second part from the binomial formula part....what exactly do we need it for? And what is the second part of the prove with 1/n<a/($c^pC_p)$

Comment: It looks like you first wanted to prove the supremum, c cannnot be 0, then tried to prove what if 0<x<1 because that makes x^p actually smaller than p, i got that, i just didnt quite get the proof.....

Comment: I want to argue that if we have $c^p < a$ then there exists some factor $f>1$ so that $c^pf^p < a$ and thus $cf>c\in B$. To do this I look at $(1+1/n)^p$ and try to bound how big this may get (which is the $1+C_p x$ part), so I can argue that such an $n$ exists that $f=1+1/n$ does indeed satisfy the given properties (i.e. $c^pf^p < a$).

Comment: Sorry one more follow up question : wouldnt this prove that $c$ is not the supremum of b and $c^p$ is not equal to $a$?

Comment: ok i just understood your proof....took me a whole day .....thanks!

Comment: No problem. As I said, you’re probably trying to prove the unique existence of the $p$-th root. A different attempt could argue that $x^p$ is continuous, and the use the intemediary value theorem.